# Как свернуть ресурс в регистре сведений по измерению (в экранной форме)? Или лучше на регистр накопления перейти?

Tags: база-данных, объекты, 1с

Мне нужно рассчитать количество пропусков всего и по уважительной причине для каждого студента (в форме, реализующей отбор по группе), а также для каждой группы (в форме, реализующей отбор по факультету) (разрабатываю конфигурацию для предметной области "Успеваемость"). То есть, сложить эти 3 и 4, и для Тивирова получить 7 пропусков всего. Или это возможно только в отчёте, но не в форме? Или в регистре накопления это реализовать? Если в регистре накопления, то как?

[image: Форма по факультету (Количество пропусков для данного семестра и факультета)]
[image: Форма по группе (Количество пропусков для данного семестра и группы)]

Answer (score 0):

Для различных расчетов, группировок используйте запросы. Регистра сведений должно быть достаточно для фиксации пропусков каждого студента.

А для отображения на форме вам подойдет "Динамический список". Он позволяет отображать данные не только отдельных справочников, регистров и.т.д. но и произвольных запросов, в том числе и с параметрами.

Параметр можно задать так:

```
ДинСписок.Параметры.УстановитьЗначениеПараметра("Студент", СпрСтудент.Ссылка);
```

Вот отличный пример - [Как установить параметр динамического списка](https://helpf.pro/faq/view/1657.html)